# I put Adblu in radiator coolant tank in Peugeot Boxer 435 Onnicar

Tags: coolant, radiator, peugeot, boxer

My coolant tank was empty and there was a plastic cane in the cockpit/dashboard, so I thought, it was water and I put some in the coolant tank. I am pretty sure it was less than 500ml.

Driver is using the vehicle, and it seems to working, engine/motor doesn't sound anything suspicious for 4 days.

Should I worry?

Does the motor has to be opened for clean up?

Comment: I'd just swap coolant for a couple of times and don't worry too much about it

Comment: Sorry, I didn't get what you mean by swap coolant? Like clean the coolant?

Comment: Just drain the contaminated coolant, refill with fresh one and drive for a while to dilute the remaining contaminations. Repeat this for two or three times..

Comment: ok, This has been done after 100 - 110 km run.

Answer (score 9):

ADBLU is a mix of uric acid and water, and you don't want acid in your cooling system as it can cause corrosion. It's not a disaster, you just need to drain your coolant out of the system and refill with fresh coolant.

From your other question it seems like you have a cooling system problem and are losing a lot of your coolant every day. If this is the case I wouldn't worry about it as a mechanic is going to do this anyway to fix your other problem.

Comment: yea, but which mechanic. I mentioned two mechnics and they are saying completly different things.

Comment: Either of what they say will require draining the coolant

Comment: do warn them there may be contaminated coolant, however!